# Issue with Spring batch metadata tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I created the spring batch metadata tables using the following link in my own oracle database

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core

But when I run my spring batch, it throws me error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Encountered fatal error executing job
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:97) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:880) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:906) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:307) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:174) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.updateStatus(AbstractJob.java:443) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:315) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
```

Currently I am using spring boot - 2.5.12 and Spring batch - 4.3.5

Do I need to make manual entries in the spring batch tables?

Many thanks for your feedback !!

Answer (score 0):

The schemas in the main branch are for the upcoming version v5, in which some columns have been removed/added, etc.

You need to use the DDL script with the same schema as your spring batch version (4.3.5) in your case:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.3.5/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql

Comment: Hello, I still get the same error after creating the tables from the link you shared.